# Confusion about Vandermonde determinant and linear dependence.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Suppose that we have $a_1f_1(x)+a_2f_2(x)+a_3f_3(x) = b_1g_1(x)+b_2g_2(x)+b_3g(x)$. All $f(x)$ are distinct, as are all $g(x)$, but we can have equality between some $f(x)$s and some $g(x)$s. Further all the scalars are positive. Therefore the the set of the functions is linearly dependent:
$$a_1f_1(x)+a_2f_2(x)+a_3f_3(x) - b_1g_1(x)-b_2g_2(x)-b_3g(x) = 0.$$

Suppose further that the functions are such that we can construct a system of equations with Vandermonde structure by evaluating at say $x$, $2x$, $3x$ and so on:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&\dots&1\\
f_1(x)&\dots & g_3(x)\\
\vdots& & \vdots\\
f_1(x)^{5} & \dots & g_3(x)^5
\end{bmatrix}
\mathbf{c} = 0
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{c}$ is just a vector of the coefficients. Since the determinant has to equal zero, we get that there must be equality with at least one of the f and g functions, wlog say $f_1=g_1$ (by the standard result of Vandermonde determinants). In other words linear dependence implies above results.

But now if I plug in $g_1 = f_1$ in the original equation, I will get:
$$(a_1 - b_1)f_1(x)+a_2f_2(x)+a_3f_3(x)-b_2g_2(x)-b_3g(x) = 0.$$ And now if I repeat the above procedure, linear dependence and Vandermonde determinant implys that also $f_2$ or $f_3$ has to be equal $g_2$ or $g_3$.

On the other hand, if instead I didn't combine $a_1f_1$ and $b_1f_1$ into $(a_1-b_1)f_1$ and instead just had:
$$a_1f_1(x) - b_1f_1(x)+a_2f_2(x)+a_3f_3(x)-b_2g_2(x)-b_3g(x) = 0$$
and built a Vandermonde determinant, then the first two columns would be equal and thus determinant already equal to zero without any implications about further equalities between the remaining $f_2$, $f_3$ and $g_2$, $g_3$ functions. Is there a conflict between the results of this and the previous paragraphs?

Also, if indeed each of the $f$ functions has to equal one of the $g$ functions by repeated application of the Vandermonde matrix, then why was this all just not implied by the very first Vandermonde determinant. What is it that requires me to apply the process iteratively?

Comment: You multiplied the Vandermonde *matrix* by a column vector, and the result has $0$ in the second coordinate. This doesn't imply that the determinant of the matrix is $0$.

Comment: But that Vandermonde matrix has two equal columns (I assume you are talking about my second last paragraph?) Would that not imply the matrix is non-invertible already?